# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host in C# Asynchronous Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, socketexception

We are trying to develop Asynchronous socket to which multiple GPS devices will connect and Server Socket will respond to them all. But There is an exception in the program in `BeginAccept` Callback, which throws an exception as **"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".**

While calling to `ReceiveCallBack` for particularly connected socket it throws this exception. Can you please help us?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using DecodeGpsPacket;


namespace GpsProtocol {
 class Server {
  private static readonly Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
  private static readonly List < Socket > clientSockets = new List < Socket > ();
  private
  const int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
  private
  const int PORT = 100;
  private static readonly byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
  private static Dictionary < string, string > DevicesList = new Dictionary < string, string > ();
  public static string Path = @ "C:\Users\Shubham\Downloads\GpsProtocol\GpsProtocol\TextFile1.txt";



  static void Main() {
   Console.Title = "Server";
   SetupServer();
   Console.ReadLine(); // When we press enter close everything
   CloseAllSockets();
  }

  private static void SetupServer() {
   Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
   serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT));
   serverSocket.Listen(0);
   serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
   Console.WriteLine("Server setup complete");
  }


  private static void CloseAllSockets() {
   foreach(Socket socket in clientSockets) {
    socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    socket.Close();
   }

   serverSocket.Close();
  }

  private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR) {
   Socket socket;

   try {
    socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
    Console.WriteLine("New Connection : {0} \n {1} \n==============", socket.RemoteEndPoint, DateTime.Now);
   } catch (ObjectDisposedException) // I cannot seem to avoid this (on exit when properly closing sockets)
   {
    return;
   }

   clientSockets.Add(socket);
   socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);
   Console.WriteLine("Client connected, waiting for request...");
   serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
  }

  private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR) {
   Socket current = (Socket) AR.AsyncState;
   int received;

   try {
    received = current.EndReceive(AR);
   } catch (SocketException) {
    Console.WriteLine("Client forcefully disconnected");
    // Don't shutdown because the socket may be disposed and its disconnected anyway.
    current.Close();
    clientSockets.Remove(current);
    return;
   }

   byte[] MainBuffer = new byte[received];
   Array.Copy(buffer, MainBuffer, received);
   try {
    current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    if (e.InnerException != null) {
     new SaveGpsInfo().LogException(e.Message, e.InnerException.Message, e.StackTrace);
    }

   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: The exception occurs when exiting? When the `serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);` raises an exception _(in AcceptCallback)_, don't continue with a `serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);`. It should be inside the try block

Comment: The exception occurs while exiting from AcceptCallback , when I call socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);

Comment: I don't know if it has something to do with it, but all clients are using the same receive buffer `private static readonly byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];` which shouldn't

Comment: yes but while receiving data from one socket connection I am stopping receiving data from remaining socket connection, so I don't think so it's a problem